# How get properties for not collection property

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a `Person` class that inherits `EntityBase`:

```
public class Person : EntityBase
{        
   virtual public string FirstName { get; set; }
   virtual public string LastName { get; set; } 
   virtual public IList<Asset> Assets { get; set; }   

}
```

And

```
public class EntityBase : IEntity
{    
   public virtual long Id { get; protected set; }
   public virtual IEnumurable<string> Errors { get; protected set; }
}
```

I need to get list of properties of `Person` class that is not collection

Now `GetProperties()` is include : `FirstName, LastName, Assets, Id, Errors` but I need only not array  properties : `FirstName, LastName, Id`

How can I get the properties that are not collection ?

Comment: Well `Assets` and `Errors` aren't actually arrays either... they're just collections.

Comment: Excuse me,
My purpose is collection

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can filter by the return type of the property. I suspect you want to filter out anything that implements `IEnumerable`, but *isn't* `string` (which implements `IEnumerable<char>`, but which you want to keep). So something like:

```
var properties = type.GetProperties()
       .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string) ||
                   !typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType));
```

Comment: You know, you should resign from SO and let people answer. Seriously, at least consider not being a robot and answer this fast.

Comment: @akanksha: Why would that not give the right result? What difference does the protected setter make?

Comment: @Jon Skeet : This is correct.
But what is difference between string and other types that it has a separate expressed?

Comment: @Ehsan: You want to keep strings - but they're collections of characters, so would otherwise be excluded.